# python csv header error

Tags: python, csv

Trying to read headers for a csv file with:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(PATH_FILE),skipinitialspace=True)
headers = reader.fieldnames

for header in sorted(set(headers)):
```

It worked on development server, throws this error on production

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Debug shows headers has None value while the csv file has headers in it.

```
headers:None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`csvreader.fieldnames` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.fieldnames):

> If not passed as a parameter when creating the object, this attribute is initialized **upon first access or when the first record is read from the file**.

So try reading the first row from the file, then `reader.fieldnames` should contain the data you need. Maybe something like adding `reader.next()`:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(PATH_FILE),skipinitialspace=True)
reader.next()
headers = reader.fieldnames
```

The documentation also says:

> *Changed in version 2.6.*

So this difference in behaviour could be due to a difference in Python version between your two systems.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're using different Python versions in your development server vs production?  In Python 2.5, the `fieldnames` attribute of a `DictReader` instance is `None` until the instance has been used to fetch at least one row.